# Displaying Images based on column value in WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a datatable queried from SQL server table.
The data table contains only one column, it will have numbers from 0 -9.
I need to display that in WPF datagrid. I have done displaying as ordinary datagrid.
But I need to display a separate picture and some text for that specific number in that column.
Is it possible thorugh Datagrid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [DataGridTemplateColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.aspx) and bind it using an `IValueConverter` that will transform your `int` into an `ImageSource`

Here is a small working example :

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:IntToImageConverter x:Key="IntToImageConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <DataGrid>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IntToImageConverter}}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Image number : " Margin="5, 0, 0, 0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

        <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
        <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>

    </DataGrid>

</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class IntToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            ImageSource result = null;
            var intValue = (int)value;
            switch (intValue)
            {
                case 0:
                    {
                        result = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"your_path_to_image_0"));
                        break;
                    }

                case 1:
                    {
                        result = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"your_path_to_image_1"));
                        break;
                    }
            }
            return result;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where should i load the datatable(queried from database server) to the datagrid??

Comment: Well that's another question :) You don't know how to retrieve data from a table and bind it to a DataGrid ? The example i gave you is for a simple DataGrid with no binding, only to illustrate how to replace the number by an image, which was your original question

Comment: I have retrived from db server. How to attach that to datagrid??

Comment: In what data structure did you retrieve it ? You should open another question for this particular matter, it has nothing to do with the original question. Moreover, it seemed like a problem you already solved as you mentionned : "I have done displaying as ordinary datagrid"

Comment: I displayed that as a text column i.e., just did binding to Itemssource of datagrid. so only i mentioned "I have done displaying as ordinary datagrid". I need to know creating this in code behind.

Comment: You just have to set the correct ItemsSource on the DataGrid then. Binding is already managed in the Cell DataTemplate.